# ViewPager Gallery replacement

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have done enough searching and finally I am asking this question.

I am converting gallery of imageviews into Viewpager backed up by PagerAdapter. I was able to achieve this:-

[image]

In onpageselected I am getting the position which I am using to get the red border.

Problem:-
Only the left most imageview is returned in onpageselected(). The rightmost imageview can never come to left and thus cannot be selected. Further on touching an imageview onpageselected() does not get called. It only gets called when you swipe it.

Questions:-
How to centre the selected imageview?
How to get the imageview position on touching it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to NathanZ he gave me some direction. Finally I had to set a OnClickListener() on the ImageView not the ViewPager.

```
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyImageView grpView = new MyImageView(ctxt);
        final int temp=position;
        grpView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                pos=temp;//This is the value what I am interested in
            }
        });
        grpView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int)(109*density), (int)(109*density)));

        myViewPager.addView(grpView);
        return grpView;
    }
```